# What happens if a Lightning channel close transaction is evicted from the mempool?

Tags: lightning-network, mempool, ln-closing-channels

I recently had a cooperative close of a Lightning channel and the two Lightning nodes agreed a fee rate of about 1 sat/vbyte for the closing transaction. (This was fine by me; I always like to keep fees low and was/am in no rush.) The transaction was evicted from my Bitcoin node's mempool a few hours later because of the recent high volume.

The transaction subsequently reappeared in my Bitcoin node's mempool. That's good, but how did it get there? I can't see anything obvious in my Lightning node's logs about observing the transaction to have been evicted, resubmitting it or noticing that the Lightning peer had resubmitted it, but maybe I just don't know what to look for.

Is the behaviour in this situation standardised? If not, how do the different Lightning implementations (particularly lnd and Core Lightning) behave?

Out of paranoia I manually saved a copy of the transaction so I could resubmit it if it got completely lost; was there any need for me to do that?

(I've edited the question in light of Mark's comment and to make explicit whether I'm referring to Bitcoin or Lightning nodes.)

Comment: There is no "the mempool". Every node has it's own mempool and chooses its own policy.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that makes sense. The transaction did disappear from my node's mempool and reappeared later on. So one possibility is that some other node (e.g. with a much larger max mempool size) still had my transaction in its mempool, keeping it alive until it could spread across the network to nodes with the default mempool limit later on - is that right?